# Use Matlab to compare values in different columns of 2 cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compare two cell arrays that contain both characters and numbers. I would like to compare specific columns and then return the values in another related column.

For example, I have two cell arrays of the forms:

```
One=         Two=
[A X 2 10      [A 1 X 2 76
 B Y 2 11       B 1 Y 2 78
 A X 5 22       C 1 Z 2 80
 B Y 5 23       D 1 X 4 98
 A X 6 28       E 1 Y 4 99
 B Y 6 28       F 1 Z 4 100
 C Z 6 28]      G 1 X 6 110
                H 1 Y 6 120]
```

And I want to be able to find everywhere column 2 and 3 of 'One' equals column 3 and 4 of 'Two' and return the specific value in column 5 of 'Two' (and ideally also the value in column 3). In this example, 'One' has an X 2, Y 2, X 6, and Y 6 in common with 'Two' so I would obtain a result that is:

```
Three=
[X 76
 Y 78
 X 110
 Y 120]
```

The cell arrays I currently have are also of different sizes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you've got a full char-matrix, you can use `ismember`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare One and Two as cell array
Also Create one empty cell named Third. You can compare and get output as

```
[m n]=size(One)
Three = {};
for i=1:m
   if ((One{i,2} == Two{i,3}) && (One{i,3} == Two{i,4}) )
       Three=[Three; {One{i,2},Two{i,5}}];
   end    
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to employ this but I keep ending up with an error because my matrix dimensions don't agree.

Comment: I tested this code before posting. Please post your code along with error. maybe I can help you then.

Comment: For the above problem, I'm now doing this:
`One={['A':'G'],['X' 'Y' 'X' 'Y' 'X' 'Y' 'Z'],[2 2 5 5 6 6 6],[10 11 22 23 28 28 28]};      
 
     Two={['A':'H'],[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1],['X' 'Y' 'Z' 'X' 'Y' 'Z' 'X' 'Y'],[2 2 2 4 4 4 6 6],[76 78 80 98 99 100 110 120]};

[m n]=size(One)
Three = {};
for i=1:m
   if ((One{i,2} == Two{i,3}) && (One{i,3} == Two{i,4}) )
       Three=[Three; {One{i,2},Two{i,5}}];
   end    
end`

Comment: I'm getting the "Error using == Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in test (line 8)
   if ((One{i,2} == Two{i,3}) && (One{i,3} == Two{i,4}) )"

Comment: You are getting error, because One{i,2} has 7 elements and Two{i,3} has 8 elements. You always compare string of same length.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said in my post that my arrays are of different sizes. Is there no way to find all of the X 2, Y 2 and whatevers in the second array? Would padding one with zeroes help?

Comment: Array of different sizes can be handled. However, when you are comparing string element of array, they are supposed to be of same length. A can never be compared with AA or AB. It won't be same. A can be compared with A of AB.

Comment: So could I add other strings (that won't be found in Two) to the end of the array?

Comment: You are not getting my point. One{i,2}=['X' 'Y' 'X' 'Y' 'X' 'Y' 'Z'] and Two{i,3} = ['X' 'Y' 'Z' 'X' 'Y' 'Z' 'X' 'Y']. So while comparing, you need to compare One with 7 chars from Two{i,3}. You can try something like this  if ((One{i,2} == Two{i,3}(1:7) ))
       if(One{i,3} == Two{i,4}) 
           Three=[Three; {One{i,2},Two{i,5}}]